# Manage memory on vector assignment

Tags: c++, vector, containers

(This question can be extended to others containers)

I can use a vector to storage a lot of data then it is important to know how the c++ manage the assignment to this container specially if I don't have a lot of memory.

a) When an assign is made to a function that return a vector the data on this vector is clean up immediately after the assign or it keep it until the last moment to receive the new data?

b) If the data is immediately destroyed, which state the vector during the function process to build the new data?

b.1) If the data has kept, that means I can have in memory two huge vectors (the old data and new data) until the assign be made (returned)?

c) And what about the move semantic? It try to use the space already created? (if the data is not destroyed immediately like asked in the first question)

To better demonstrate it I wrote a tiny program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> func2() {
    vector<string> f2(200000, string(20,'a'));
    return f2;
}

vector<string> func4() {
    vector<string> f4(400000, string(40,'b'));
    //Now I have in memory 400000X40 + 200000X20?
    return f4;
    //after assignment I know I have just f4 content
}

vector<string> func1() {
    vector<string> f1(100000, string(10,'c'));
    return f10;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> mVec;

    mVec = func2(); //Create internally a vector with 20 units string with 20 'b' inside

    mVec = func4(); //Create internally a vector with 40 units string with 40 'b' inside

    mVec = func1(); //Create internally a vector with 10 units string with 10 'b' inside

    return 0;
}
```

If the move semantic really use the existent space, how it works when mVec has less data and need to assign more (func2 to func4) or vice-versa (func4 to func1).

Comment: `mVec = func2()` uses move assignment; the internal data storage allocated by `f2` within the function is handed over to `mVec`. No further allocation or copying is performed. Same with `mVec = func4()` - storage is allocated inside the function, then handed over to `mVec`; the latter deallocates its previous data before accepting ownership of the new one. Same with `mVec = func1()`.

Comment: A more efficient method may be to pass the vector by reference to the function.  This may eliminate some copying of the vector (depends on optimization settings and compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When func4() is called, right before return statement, you surely have two big vectors. And you have them in memory right up to the point of assignment.

As for c), vector is contigous container, so when you create new vector, it will be stored in memory as a whole, not one part in memory block 1 and the other part in memory block 127 (just an example).

My suggestion would be, to use passing vector (which will be refiled) by reference, and resize it correctly before filling, that way you may avoid asignment of whole vector.

Code sample (optimization suggestion):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::fill
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void func2(vector<string>& vec) {
    vec.resize(200000);
    fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), string(20, 'a'));
}

void func4(vector<string>& vec) {
    vec.resize(400000);
    fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), string(40, 'b'));
}

void func1(vector<string>& vec) {
    vec.resize(100000);
    fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), string(10, 'c'));
}

int main() {
    vector<string> mVec;

    func2(mVec); //Create internally a vector with 20 units string with 20 'b' inside

    func4(mVec); //Create internally a vector with 40 units string with 40 'b' inside

    func1(mVec); //Create internally a vector with 10 units string with 10 'b' inside

    return 0;
}
```